# how to hide the float action button only on the 1st fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Please tell me how to hide the Floating Action button only on the 1st fragment in Android Studio?
I use Navigation Drawer, here is a code in MainActivity.java where I call the fragments:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FirstFragment fragment1;
    SecondFragment fragment2;
    ThirdFragment fragment3;
    


    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static Context currentContext;

  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MainActivity.currentContext = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });



        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.bringToFront();

        fragment1 = new FirstFragment();
        fragment2 = new SecondFragment();
        fragment3 = new ThirdFragment();
        
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment1).commit();
        if (savedInstanceState==null){
           }

       
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }





@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentTransaction ftrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        String title = "App Name";

        switch (id) {
            case (R.id.nav_fr2):
                ftrans.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment2);
                title="Fragment 2";
                break;

            case (R.id.nav_fr3):
                ftrans.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment3);
                title="Fragment 3";
                break;

           
            default:
                ftrans.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment1);
                break;
        }
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        ftrans.commit();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Here is a code of my main activity. when I add fab.setVisibility(View.GONE); Android Studio display me an error "Cannot resolve symbol fab". When I add in this block FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab); the fab not displayed in all fragments.

Comment: I think you can set `fab.setVisibility(View.GONE)`  inside `default` case which is fragment 1 and for other cases you can set `fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: @MayurGajra thank you for your answer, but when I add fab.setVisibility(View.GONE); Android Studio display me an error "Cannot resolve symbol fab". When I add in this block FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab); the fab not displayed in all fragments.

Comment: Can you please post code how you're decalring the fab and where you're declaring it? I need layout and activity code to see how we can achieve this.

Comment: @MayurGajra I added code to initial question

Comment: Ok. Let me have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your `fab` a class level variable instead of local and then change the visibility to your needs following is the example:

```
    FirstFragment fragment1;
    SecondFragment fragment2;
    ThirdFragment fragment3;



    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static Context currentContext;

    // declare it here
    FloatingActionButton fab;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MainActivity.currentContext = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //assign here like this
        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });



        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.bringToFront();

        fragment1 = new FirstFragment();
        fragment2 = new SecondFragment();
        fragment3 = new ThirdFragment();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment1).commit();
        if (savedInstanceState==null){
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentTransaction ftrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        String title = "App Name";

        switch (id) {
            case (R.id.nav_fr2):
                // set this visible when fragment 2 selected
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ftrans.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment2);
                title="Fragment 2";
                break;

            case (R.id.nav_fr3):
                // set this visible when fragment 3 selected
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ftrans.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment3);
                title="Fragment 3";
                break;


            default:
                // hide when fragment 1 selected
                fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ftrans.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment1);
                break;
        }
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        ftrans.commit();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @luska You can mark this answer as accepted if it works for you.